# How to change colour theme in ggplot

Tags: r

I have runned the following code:

```
ggplot(Cars)) +
geom_point(aes(colour = Model)) +
labs(title = "Cars in the US") +
labs(colour = "USD")
```

**And the small box to the right of the plot turns in a blue tone (down below). However I want to have it in two version, on in green tone and the other in red tone (red, orange, yellow depending on value).** How do I do that?

[image]

Comment: So you want two different color bars? This is possible, but they have to map to some variable. Could you give us an example of how this would work? In the example you have given there is only a single variable assigned to color, so there is nothing for a second color bar to represent.

Answer (score 1):

If you want two different graphs with colors of your choice for each one, you could do this with the function `scale_color_gradient`

```
### Miscellaneous
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
data(cars)

### Initiating plots
firstPlot <- ggplot(cars, aes(x=speed, y=dist)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = speed)) +
  labs(title = "Cars in the US") +
  labs(colour = "USD") + 
  scale_color_gradient2(midpoint=15, 
                        low="yellow", 
                        mid="orange", 
                        high="red", space="Lab")

secondPlot <- ggplot(cars, aes(x=speed, y=dist)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = speed)) +
  labs(title = "Cars in the US") +
  labs(colour = "USD") + 
  scale_color_gradient2(midpoint=15, 
                        low="#56ffba", 
                        mid="#2bc888", 
                        high="#078954", space="Lab")

### Display plots
ggarrange(firstPlot, secondPlot, nrow=1, ncol=2)
```

[image]